# why does `($(hostname -I))` expand to first word of list of IPs?

Tags: bash

I am using the following construct to get the first IP of my host.

```
firstip=($(hostname -I))
```

The hostname command returns all IPs of my box, but not 127.x.x.x, which is exactly what I want. I use the first IP returned.

But I do not understand the syntax I am using. According to bash manual `()` evaluates the expression within the brackets and returns the result. Word splitting is not applied to assignments.

I would have expected it to expand to all IPs, but it returns the first word (IFS is set to default, aka blank). If I do not use the brackets, `firstip` is assigned the list of IPs.

Is it safe to assume that `variable=(list)` assigns the first word of `list` to `variable`? And where is this explained in the bash man page?

Comment: What is output of `declare -p firstip` ?

Comment: It assigns the entire list, but if you use `$variable` to expand it instead of `"${variable[@]}"`, you're ignoring the rest. `"$array"` is the same as `"${array[0]}"`, taking only the first entry.

Comment: ...that said, this isn't a good practice way to use arrays in bash at all. See [BashPitfalls #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy sounds like an explanation, array definition according to manpage is required to be `(value, ... valuex)` where `value` is of the forn `[index]=value)`. So, bash has a short form of array definition with `(list)` that is not really documented? Or is that the meaning of the sentence `Indexed  array  assignments  do  not require anything but string.` I really want a deeper understanding of the syntax I am using here :-)

Comment: So, `array=( "first item" "second item" "third item" )` is unambiguous and works well -- same for `array=( "$first_item" "$second_item" "$third_item" )` -- but that's **not** the case for `array=( $foo )`, even if someone previously ran `foo='"first item" "second item" "third item"'`; the values are subject to string-splitting and glob expansion, which results in something very similar to the set of bugs described in [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: ...see the opening summary to [BashPitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) (re: "[always use quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) and never use [WordSplitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) for any reason!"), expanded by the examples of common mistakes/bugs later in the page for more context. :)

Comment: ...to expand on the example I gave above, of `foo='"first item" "second item" "third item"'; array=( $foo )`, you get `"first` as a word, `item"` as a second word, &c., thus expanding to a total of six array elements rather than three -- and if there were a whitespace-surrounded `*`, it would be replaced with a list of files in the current working directory.

Comment: ...and yes, you correctly interpreted the manual: the ability to get indexes implicitly assigned counting up from 0 when no explicit index values are provided is exactly what the "only *string* is required" means in the context at hand.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy and if you had written all this as an answer I could have accepted it :-)

Comment: Yes, but it would be a duplicate; if I were going to write an answer, it would be on the existing instance of the question -- since the goal of duplicates is to funnel folks from what are ideally differently-asked question instances (thus catching different search terms between them) to one canonical set of answers, so focus can be put on curating/improving a single instance, rather than having different variants strewn about the site.

Comment: (This is part of why duplicate questions that aren't heavily downvoted don't get automatically deleted, and can in fact be upvoted: They act as signposts pointing towards those canonical instances, and as such add value to the knowledgebase).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I fail to see the duplicate helping the user.

Comment: @MikeQ, ...can you explain in more detail what aspect of this question isn't addressed in the linked duplicate? The answers on the linked question explicitly describe how to adjust an expansion to include all entries of an array rather than only the first, and thus explain *why* the naive syntax (which wasn't shown in this question but had to be inferred -- if this wasn't a duplicate, it would have needed edits to comply with [mcve] rules) evaluates only to the first entry.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy the linked URL describes how the array is already populated, one step past what this user is stuck at.

Comment: @MikeQ, ...the user here *assumed* that the behavior they were asking about was happening in the assignment phase (and thus didn't show the expansion in their question), but that assumption was wrong -- the surprising behavior was in fact in the expansion phase, or else my comments wouldn't have been helpful to them.

Comment: ...frankly, that makes this the kind of duplicate we want to have more of: A *non-obvious* one, where someone is likely to find it when they wouldn't have found the older post (and wouldn't be aware that the prior post was helpful to them without expert guidance to that effect).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I thought the issue was that it was all being assigned to the first array element instead building out an array from the command one to one. I think I might be wrong, can't test it .

Comment: @MikeQ, ...so, the OP here had working code for extracting only the first IP address for their host, but didn't understand *why* it worked, because they expected the array to contain every address, not just the one they wanted. (And, actually, it *did* contain every address, but the expansion mechanism in use was hiding the others). As the OP says, *"I would have expected it to expand to all IPs, but it returns the first word"*, and they're explicit (both in the variable name and elsewhere in the text) that that first word is exactly what they want.